# Android Button Controller class

Tags: android, view, imagebutton

I am trying to make a class to handle most of the common buttons in a app I am making.
I just don't know how to do this. I have made a class with a method ButtonPressed which will perform the action of each button that is pressed. 
I tried this a few ways but I think what comes down to is that I am not passing the view right to the class. Is there a better way of doing this?
Thank you for any help. The error that it gives me is a Nullpoint reference. Which I think is due to not knowing where to look for the view.

The main focus here is to allow for this button controller class to handle the buttons that are in common to each activity by just calling the button being pressed. I don't want to keep copying and pasting the button controls every time i change something in each activity.

Here is the buttonPressed class

```
public class ButtonControler extends AppCompatActivity {


public ButtonControler(){}

public void buttonPressed()
{
    //add the buttons contorls
    //if the top button is pushed get the promotion page
    final ImageButton promo = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.apivita);
    promo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent getPromos = new Intent(v.getContext(),PromotionMain.class);
            startActivity(getPromos);
        }
    });
    //if the button 1  is pushed get the defulat webview page
    final ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Button1: ", "Pressed");
            Intent button1Pressed = new Intent(v.getContext(),MyWebViewMain.class);
            startActivity(button1Pressed);
        }
    });


    //if the cart is pushed get the cart webview page
    final ImageButton cart = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Cart: ","Pressed");
            Intent myCart = new Intent(v.getContext(),Cart.class);
            startActivity(myCart);
        }
    });

    //if the button 3  is pushed get the defulat webview page
    final ImageButton button3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Button3: ","Pressed");
            Intent buttonPressed = new Intent(v.getContext(),MyWebViewMain.class);
            startActivity(buttonPressed);
        }
    });

    //if the button 4  is pushed get the defulat webview page
    final ImageButton button4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Button4: ","Pressed");
            Intent buttonPressed = new Intent(v.getContext(),MyWebViewMain.class);
            startActivity(buttonPressed);
        }
    });

    //if the Store list  is pushed get the defulat webview page
    final ImageButton storeList = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    storeList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("StoreList: ","Pressed");
            Intent myStoreList = new Intent(v.getContext(),StoreList.class);
            startActivity(myStoreList);
        }
    });

    //if the Store list  is pushed get the notification
    final Button notification = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gcmlogo);
    notification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Notificatiion: ","Pressed");
            Intent myNotification = new Intent(v.getContext(),GCMMainActivity.class);
            startActivity(myNotification);
        }
    });

    //if the Store list  is pushed get the notification
    final Button myPage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mypage);
    myPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("MyPage: ","Pressed");
            //read the stored values
            String storedUser = CustomerPerferences.readString(getApplicationContext(), CustomerPerferences.USER_NAME, "");
            String storedPass =CustomerPerferences.readString(getApplicationContext(), CustomerPerferences.PASSWORD, "");
            //see if use has entered a username and password
            if(storedUser.equals("USER_NAME"))
            {
                Log.d("Loging in", "Go!");
                Intent goToLogin = new Intent(v.getContext(),LoginPage.class);
                startActivity(goToLogin);
            }else
            {

                Intent goToLogin = new Intent(v.getContext(),CustomerPage.class);
                goToLogin.putExtra("user_name", storedUser);
                startActivity(goToLogin);
            }

        }
    });
```

And this is a sample of one of the main pages that will used the button controller class

```
public class PromotionMain extends AppCompatActivity {

//gobal variables
  //these are where the paths will be stored
final ArrayList<String> pictureArray = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayList<String> pathArray = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayList<String> labelArray = new ArrayList<String>();
//Promotiion website
final String promos = myUrl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.promotion_layout);

    //parse the JSON string
    //parse the JSON string
    JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();

    try {
        jp.parsesData(promos, pictureArray, pathArray, labelArray);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<ListItem> listData = getListData();

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, listData));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        //here is a method to either send the user to the poduct page
        //or to the main page in the app
        //open a new activity and close this one down
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            ListItem promoData = (ListItem) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //Toast.makeText(PromotionMain.this, "Selected :" + " " + promoData.getPathUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //open up a new activity and send it to this site http://52.68.68.86/magento
            //lest open up the corrisponding webpage
            Intent reDirect = new Intent();
            reDirect.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            reDirect.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            //need to make sure that if it is not a url them do nothing in future rendtions
            //other wise it will crash the app
            reDirect.setData(Uri.parse(promoData.getPathUrl()));
            String newUrl = Uri.parse(promoData.getPathUrl()).toString();
            //check to see if there is a path for the promotion
            if (newUrl.contains("http")) {
                startActivity(reDirect);
            } else {
                //if not do nothing
                Log.d("Path URL: ", " is null");
            }

        }
    });

    //add the buttons contorls
   // buttonPressed();
    ButtonControler bc = new ButtonControler();
    bc.buttonPressed();
    //ButtonControler bc = new ButtonControler();
    //bc.pressed(promo,cart,storeList,button1,button3,button4,null);

}
private ArrayList<ListItem> getListData() {
    ArrayList<ListItem> listGetData = new ArrayList<ListItem>();


    //get the url for the image from the picture array list
    for (int i = 0; i < pictureArray.size(); i++) {
        ListItem imageData = new ListItem();
        imageData.setUrl(pictureArray.get(i));
        imageData.setPathUrl(pathArray.get(i));
        imageData.setLableTitle(labelArray.get(i));
        listGetData.add(imageData);

    }
    return listGetData;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all change this:

```
public class ButtonControler extends AppCompatActivity
```

to

```
public class ButtonControler
```

Second pass the Activity to `public void buttonPressed()`

like

```
public void buttonPressed(Activity activity)
```

Then change each findViewById to

```
final ImageButton promo = (ImageButton)activity.findViewById(R.id.apivita);
```

And call this method from activity like this

```
ButtonControler bc = new ButtonControler();
bc.buttonPressed(this);
```

You are creating a different activity each time and calling findViewById on it. Which doesn't have a view also is not even started.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you for teaching me how to pass the activity that has stopped me from doing a lot. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

if you want to go to a certain activity when a button is pressed you can do some thing like that it is simple , and you can add whatever action to it or even call a function

```
public class ListGroupsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button profile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GoToProfile);
    Button wall =(Button) findViewById(R.id.GoToWall);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        profile.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
        wall.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),WallActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change you ButtonControler as following

```
public class ButtonControler {

    Activity mActivity;

    public ButtonControler(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public void buttonPressed() {
        //add the buttons contorls
        //if the top button is pushed get the promotion page
        final ImageButton promo = (ImageButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.apivita);
        promo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent getPromos = new Intent(v.getContext(), PromotionMain.class);
                mActivity.startActivity(getPromos);
            }
        });
        //if the button 1  is pushed get the defulat webview page
        final ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Button1: ", "Pressed");
                Intent button1Pressed = new Intent(v.getContext(), MyWebViewMain.class);
                mActivity.startActivity(button1Pressed);
            }
        });


        //if the cart is pushed get the cart webview page
        final ImageButton cart = (ImageButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Cart: ", "Pressed");
                Intent myCart = new Intent(v.getContext(), Cart.class);
                mActivity.startActivity(myCart);
            }
        });

        //if the button 3  is pushed get the defulat webview page
        final ImageButton button3 = (ImageButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Button3: ", "Pressed");
                Intent buttonPressed = new Intent(v.getContext(), MyWebViewMain.class);
                mActivity.startActivity(buttonPressed);
            }
        });

        //if the button 4  is pushed get the defulat webview page
        final ImageButton button4 = (ImageButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Button4: ", "Pressed");
                Intent buttonPressed = new Intent(v.getContext(), MyWebViewMain.class);
                mActivity.startActivity(buttonPressed);
            }
        });

        //if the Store list  is pushed get the defulat webview page
        final ImageButton storeList = (ImageButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.button5);
        storeList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("StoreList: ", "Pressed");
                Intent myStoreList = new Intent(v.getContext(), StoreList.class);
                mActivity.startActivity(myStoreList);
            }
        });

        //if the Store list  is pushed get the notification
        final Button notification = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.gcmlogo);
        notification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Notificatiion: ", "Pressed");
                Intent myNotification = new Intent(v.getContext(), GCMMainActivity.class);
                mActivity.startActivity(myNotification);
            }
        });

        //if the Store list  is pushed get the notification
        final Button myPage = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.mypage);
        myPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("MyPage: ", "Pressed");
                //read the stored values
                String storedUser = CustomerPerferences.readString(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), CustomerPerferences.USER_NAME, "");
                String storedPass = CustomerPerferences.readString(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), CustomerPerferences.PASSWORD, "");
                //see if use has entered a username and password
                if (storedUser.equals("USER_NAME")) {
                    Log.d("Loging in", "Go!");
                    Intent goToLogin = new Intent(v.getContext(), LoginPage.class);
                    mActivity.startActivity(goToLogin);
                } else {

                    Intent goToLogin = new Intent(v.getContext(), CustomerPage.class);
                    goToLogin.putExtra("user_name", storedUser);
                    mActivity.startActivity(goToLogin);
                }

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Currently don't know your package name so replace the R with your.package.name.R

```
final ImageButton promo = (ImageButton) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.apivita);
```

to

```
final ImageButton promo = (ImageButton) mActivity.findViewById(com.example.pagerview.R.id.apivita);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, let `PromotionMain` class `extends` `ButtonControler` class. Rather than AppCompatActivity.